# Fetching a react component from a server

Tags: reactjs, express, components

Let's say I have an application with a component named "Protected"

```
**<Protected />**
```

This component should be "protected", and only admin users should have access to them (because it contains secret in formations)

But there are 2 problems.

- 1. I can't store it on the react application using a protected route on react router. (because my application can be easily reversed)
- 2. I can't fetch only the data from the server, I need to fetch the whole component.

I searched about React server side rendering but I didn't fully understand if it's possible.

Can I do this with React server side rendering? Are there more efficient ways?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to fetch a component rather than data from your server?

Comment: This is way much easier to organize.